# I'm using azure pipelines for deployment. I want to stop consuming the messages from kafka in all my POD's?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Consider 2 pods -> pod-a, pod-b.
kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(listenerId).stop() is running in any of the pod
say pod-b. Since we are consuming messages in pod-a, process is not stopping. Is there any solution to control this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use Spring Cloud Bus concepts for these kind of tasks:
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-bus

There is nothing to do from Spring for Apache Kafka perspective.